# Where is the response size in Squid's access.log?

Tags: proxy, logging, squid, bandwidth

I need to make a program that logs bandwidth usage per-user of a squid proxy. In my access.log I see output such as...

```
1481377143.042      0 104.123.25.183 TCP_DENIED/407 3829 CONNECT scontent.xx.fbcdn.net:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1481377143.403      0 104.123.25.183 TCP_DENIED/407 3793 CONNECT cx.atdmt.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1481377277.865 134623 104.123.25.183 TCP_MISS/200 4118 CONNECT scontent.xx.fbcdn.net:443 star7 HIER_DIRECT/2a03:2880:f022:b:face:b00c:0:3 -
1481377277.868 134626 104.123.25.183 TCP_MISS/200 4116 CONNECT scontent.xx.fbcdn.net:443 star7 HIER_DIRECT/2a03:2880:f022:b:face:b00c:0:3 -
```

I believe the response size in bytes is supposed to be in there but which entry is it? I realize header size isn't logged so the accuracy won't be perfect but it should be accurate enough. I don't know any better way to keep track of squid user bandwidth usage so this will have to do but I need to know which is the size entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native log format is:

```
"%9d.%03d %6d %s %s/%03d %d %s %s %s %s%s/%s %s"
```

With the 5th part (%d after %s/%03d) being:

> **bytes** The size is the amount of data delivered to the client. Mind
>   that this does not constitute the net object size, as headers are also
>   counted. Also, failed requests may deliver an error page, the size of
>   which is also logged here.

ref: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/LogFormat

Answer (score 1):

Looks like here http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/LogFormat#http_status_codes they say it's the entry right after the http status code so 3829, 3793, etc.